# Add support for receiving Service Bus messages in batch

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-webjobs

There are a lot of scenarios where batching message processing is far more efficient than working with an individual message.

```
public void Handle([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue")] BrokeredMessage[] messages)
{
  // Process the batch of messages  
}
```

My scenario is :: I am using service bus queue. I want to process queued messages at particular interval of time in batch.

For example :: Per 10 seconds of interval time, I want to trigger a function to process all messages inside queue

Comment: I implemented webjob in .net core. Itried to use messageReceiver.ReceiveAsync(numberofMessages, TimeSpan) but I am receiving only one message

Answer (score 3):

`ServiceBusTrigger` is not designed to work with batches. Instead, it's designed to be a message pump providing you one message at a time. Azure Functions infrastructure takes care of creating listener and completing the message when Function is done.

If you need batches, suggest to look into [Azure Service Bus with EventGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-concept).

> The key scenario of this feature is that Service Bus queues or subscriptions with a low volume of messages do not need to have a receiver that polls for messages continuously.

With this approach, you could have a Function subscribe and triggered on `ActiveMessagesAvailableWithNoListeners` event and receive messages in batch.

Answer (score 3):

Batching is supported in `ServiceBusTrigger` from ver 4.1.0 but for your scenario as suggested `TimerTrigger` would be more appropriate.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/15

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/releases/tag/v4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Azure Service Bus provides Batch operations through SDK. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.receivebatch?view=azure-dotnet) for achieving it.

Azure Function Service Bus trigger gets triggered only when a message is en queued into the Queue.

As your requirement is to check for messages at regular intervals and receive messages in batch, you can process messages in batch inside Azure Function with [Timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function)